# Run 2 sites on iis express with CommandPrompt

Tags: cmd, iis-express

i have 2 sites written by asp.net mvc and wanna to run them by cmd

i do this in cmd and first site comes up and run well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /path:"c:\Users\ali\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\firstSite" /port:18297
```

but i cant write second command to run second site, when i press any key in cmd,it says:

**Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express**

however i can open another cmd window and execute second command in it,but i want to write 2 command in a batch file

how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried with `start "" iisexpress /path.....`?

Comment: thank you so much it worked,i write first command with (start "") and batch file opens 2 window

Comment: @MCND please write your comment as answer,maybe help somebody